# multiple different buttons with different value, but only first one is used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a small "RPG" CYOA but I came across a problem with my "choice box" as only the first choice box is used as an attempt to pick other choices will lead to the same choice outcome as the first choice.

I assumed I need to set an array for the value of those buttons, but got no idea if the problem lay with this missing array or something else. Here is Javascript that are mixed with Jquery. The area where the code error is highlight with bold... well, considering I can't place those in Code as bold, it will be tagged with ** **

```
//Use this as script 3 is raw button scenario and script 3 is raw input scenario, this script is playground for hybrid

// JavaScript Document

//SETS ALL VARIABLES FOR THE GAME

    //Mechanic Variables
    //

    //locationexplored
    currentland = "Star Nexus";
    //

    //inventory
    Basicgear = true;
    Advancedgear = false;
    //

    //Lores
    planetname = "güzel dağ" // name of planet in turkish which mean beautiful mountain, given by Indiya.
    planetnameskip = "<p>güzel dağ</p>" // same but with line break.
    planetnamebold = "<b>güzel dağ</b>" // same but with bold.
    //

    //Origins
    originmode = false
    male = false // just change what people call you, no impact on story.
    female = false // just change what people call you, no impact on story.
    blankobg = false // blank easy mode, you have no weakness but no strength.
    bountyhunterobg = false // you pay money for your faction, you have strength of prestart equipment and companions. but weakness of have to support them with credits.
    mercenaryobg = false // You get stuff for your employer, you have strength of prestart base paid by your boss. but weakness of have to get stuff for your boss.
    //

//

//"<b><br><br>Origin: I don't remember...</b> " + "<b><br><br>Origin: For the money!</b> " + "<b><br><br>Origin: My employer want me here. </b>"

//$("<p>Hello</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder_choice")
//$("<center><button id='command_button' size='50'>Origin: I don't remember...</button></center><br>").insertBefore("#placeholder_choice")
//$("<center><button id='command_button' size='50'>Bye</button></center>").insertBefore("#placeholder_choice");

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#command_line").fadeOut(0000);
    $("#command_button_core").fadeIn(0000);

    $('<p>Welcome to Text Text 7. At any time you may type "help" for a list of commands that you can use.</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(0000);

    $("<p>You woke up as alarm ranging at your ears. Groaning, you got up and look outside the viewport of your room. You look at a massive space station. Hello, welcome to the Star Nexus, that are orbiting the planet by the name of " + planetnamebold + ".</p> <p>Ahh, yes. I decide to come to this planet because it was recently discovered to have carcass of Illuminated Horror within the planet core. This give the planet the properities of magic, which make it valuable for bounty hunting for the elites. It a good place to go to for ___</p> <p>Please state your Origins for this game. Here your options. </p>").insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(0000, function(){
        originmode = true;
    });

    **
    //Blank Origin
    $("<center><button class='command_button' size='50' value='Blank'>Origin: I don't remember...</button></center><br>").insertBefore("#placeholder_choice");
    //
    //Bounty Hunter Origin
    $("<center><button class='command_button' size='50' value='Bounty Hunter'>Origin: For the money!</button></center><br>").insertBefore("#placeholder_choice");
    //
    //Mercenary Origin
    $("<center><button class='command_button' size='50' value='Mercenary'>Origin: My employer want me here.</button></center><br>").insertBefore("#placeholder_choice");
    //
    **

    $(document).on("click", "#command_button_core", function() {
        $("#command_button_core").fadeOut(0000);
        $(".command_button").fadeIn(0000);
    })

    $(document).on("click", ".command_button", function() {

        var button = $(".command_button").val();

            //Set Origin to Blank
            if (button == "Blank") {
                if (originmode == true && blankobg == false && bountyhunterobg == false && mercenaryobg == false) {
                    blankobg = true;
                    $("<p>I don't really remember why I am here, but I can tell that this is my chance for new life.</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder");
                    $(".command_button").fadeOut(0000);
                }
                else $("<p>Sorry, but you can't change your origin, now that have been set.</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder");
            }
            //

            //set origin to bounty hunter
            else if (button == "Bounty Hunter"){
                if (originmode == true && blankobg == false && bountyhunterobg == false && mercenaryobg == false) {
                    bountyhunterobg = true;
                    $("<p>I came here with my gang to get rich!</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder");
                    $(".command_button").fadeOut(0000);
                }
                else $("<p>Sorry, but you can't change your origin, now that have been set.</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder");
            }
            //

            //set origin to mercenary
            else if (button == "Mercenary"){
                if (originmode == true && blankobg == false && bountyhunterobg == false && mercenaryobg == false) {
                    mercenaryobg = true;
                    $("<p>My boss want me to stay here and find something fancy and valuable and deliver it to him.</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder");
                    $(".command_button").fadeOut(0000);
                }
                else $("<p>Sorry, but you can't change your origin, now that have been set.</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder");
            }
            //

            //When your origins fail
            else
                $("<p>You got this as value: "+"<b>'"+button+"'</b>"+" - but something went wrong!"+"</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder");
            //


        $("form").submit(function() {
            var input = $("#command_line").val();

            $("#console").scrollTop($("#console")[0].scrollHeight);

            $("#command_line").val("");
        });
    });
});
```

and this is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="../../jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Text Test 7</title>
</head>
<body>

    </div>

    <div id="container"> <!--Group everything-->

        <div id="console"> <!--All narrative elements here-->

            <p id="story_inventory"></p>

        </div>

    <div id="placeholder"></div> <!--ALLOWS CONTENT TO BE INSERTED BEFORE THIS-->



    <form onsubmit="return false;"> <!--INPUT-->

        <center><input type="text" id="command_line" size="50" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"></center>

        <br>
    </form>

    <div id="placeholder_choice"></div> <!--Allows choice to be inserted before this-->

    <center><button id="command_button_core" size="50">Next</button></center>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If anyone know a link where I can give you guy the editor such as TryItEditor where I can save the work and showcase it to you guys, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in yor event callback. When you call

`$(".command_button")`

you are given an array with the three buttons with this class. Calling `.val()` on the array will return the value of the first one.

An event callback in jQuery receives a `this` keyword that references the element that triggered the event. In your case you need to use this keywork to have access to which button was clicked.

Try changing your code to

```
//var button = $(".command_button").val();
var button = $(this).val();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have see people using (this), but never bothered to use it myself as I don't know how does it know which this to take from, but seem I will need to look it up more for any use that I may have missed. Also, I wasn't aware that $(".command_button) already called it an array. I guess there was already code behind this part of Jquery that detect whatever it a array if received more than one input or by itself. I will mark this as completed.